# How to store access token and refresh token in browser cookie and perform token refresh in a spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to store access token and refresh token in browser cookie to support clustered based authentication / authorization using spring boot. So that if my request goes to any of the hosts, they can read the cookie and decrypt it and confirm if the user is authorized or not, if not and refresh token is present and valid, it can perform token refresh.

To store access token in cookie I found two approaches :

1. By implementing SecurityContextRepository, which gives me loadContext, saveContext, containsContext to get if token is present in cookie, to save tokens in context and check if token is present in cookie.
2. By following [Store token from OAuth2 server in cookie using Spring OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923418/store-token-from-oauth2-server-in-cookie-using-spring-oauth) and creating filter to store it.

I'm new to spring security and cannot determine which one to follow. Any guide will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store tokens in cookies. Store it in session.

According to latest [Spring Security team recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), the OAuth2 client getting and storing tokens should run on your servers and be "confidential" (use a secret). It also safer that your tokens are never exposed to the Internet and users devices.

The option [I use for such scenarios](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) is configuring `spring-cloud-gateway`:

- as OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` (using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`)
- with `TokenRelay=` filter to replace session cookie with the access token in session before forwarding a request from a front-end to a stateless resource server

So yes, the gateway is stateful and requires CSRF protection, but it has very little responsibilities (routing and tokens storage) and easily integrates with Spring Session if you want more than one instance (for scalability or fault tolerance reasons).